# How to pull JSON data from two different sources?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was wondering if there is a way to pull and use JSON data from two different sources. Currently, the code looks like this:

```
//JSON1
$.getJSON('url1',function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key,val){
        //code
    });

});

//JSON2
$.getJSON('url2',function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key,val){
        //code
    });

});
```

When I do this, i seems that variables created from one JSON function aren't available in the other one, which makes it hard for them to be useful together. 
Is there a better way to have these two work together?

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. there is **NO** guarantee as to what order the responses to you two calls will come in, or if they'll come in at all. your `url2` response could come in 0.03 seconds after you issue the call, and the `url` response can come in 2 hours later, which means the url2 code cannot do anything with url1 variables, because they won't be avaialble for another 2hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable declared within the functions using `var` (or blocks, using `let`) are not available outside of the functions (or blocks).

```
$.getJSON('url1',function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key,val){
        var only_accessible_here = key;
    });

});
```

So if you want variables that are accessible outside the scope of the function they are declared in, you need to declare them outside of the function they are used in.

```
var combined_stuff = ''

$.getJSON('url1',function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key,val){
        combined_stuff += val;
    });

});

//JSON2
$.getJSON('url2',function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key,val){
         combined_stuff += val;
    });

});
```

As Marc B says, there is no way to know which order the `combined_stuff` variable will be updated, either by `JSON1` first, or by `JSON2` first, or by only one, if one of the `getJSON` calls fail, or by neither if both fail.

If the order of updating is important, call the one you want to use second in the function of the one you want to call first.

```
var combined_stuff = ''

$.getJSON('url1',function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key,val){
        combined_stuff += val;

        //JSON2
        $.getJSON('url2',function(data){
            $.each(data,function(key,val){
                 combined_stuff += val;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. The only problem with now is that for some reason even if I declare the variables outside of the two json functions, they are for some reason not available outside the two (within $(document.ready())), even if a write an alert to display the value of a variable after all that code, (undefined).

Comment: I don't know the shape of your code, so I can't tell you for sure. It still seems like a scope problem (trying to access the variable outside of the scope it is declared in), or a timing issue (the async call back not finishing before you call the alert).

Answer (score 2):

This function takes an array of urls and a callback as parameters:

```
function getMultiJSON(urlList,callback) {
  var respList = {};
  var doneCount = 0;

  for(var x = 0; x < urlList.length; x++) {
    (function(url){
      $.getJSON(url,function(data){
          respList[url] = data;
          doneCount++;

          if(doneCount === urlList.length) {
            callback(respList);
          }
      });

    })(urlList[x]);
  }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
getMultiJSON(['url1','url2'],function(response) {

     // in this case response would have 2 properties,
     //
     // response.url1  data for url1
     // response.url2  data for url2

     // continue logic here
});
```

You might want to add a timeout as the function will never call your handler should any of the URLs fail to load

Answer (score 0):

Easily using the open source project jinqJs (http://www.jinqJs.com)

```
var data1 = jinqJs().from('http://....').select();
var data2 = jinqJs().from('http://....').select();

var result = jinqJs().from(data1, data2).select();
```

The example does a sync call, you can do an async call by doing something like this:

```
var data1 = null;
jinqJs().from('http://....', function(self){ data1 = self.select(); });
```

Result will contain both results combined.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the endpoint, you could make it return all of the data you want in one shot. Then your data would look like:

```
{
    "url1_data": url1_json_data,
    "url2_data": url2_json_data
}
```

If you still have 2 endpoints you need to hit, you can pass the result of your first ajax call to the second function (but this makes your 2 ajax calls synchronous):

```
function getJson1(){
    $.getJSON('url1',function(data){
        getJson2(data);
    });
}
function getJson2(json1Data){
    $.getJSON('url2',function(data){
        //Do stuff with json1 and json2 data
    });
}
getJson1();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use $.when function available in jquery to execute both the methods in parallel and then take the action. See the code snipped below,

```js
var json1 = [], json2 = [];

$.when(GetJson1(), GetJson2()).always(function () {
  
  //this code will execute only after getjson1 and getjson2 methods are run executed
  
  if (json1.length > 0)
    {
       $.each(json1,function(key,val){
        //code
        });
      }
  
    
  if (json2.length > 0)
    {
       $.each(json2,function(key,val){
        //code
        });
      }
  
  });

function GetJson1()
{
  
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'url1',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                if (data != null) {
                    json1 = data;
                }               
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                json1 = [];//just initialize to avoid js error
            }
}

function GetJson2()
{
  return $.ajax({
            url: 'url2',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                if (data != null) {
                    json2 = data;
                }               
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                json2 = [];//just initialize to avoid js error
            }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned data from each AJAX call are not available outside its own callback function. I'm sure there are more elegant (complex?) solutions, but a couple of simple, Occamic, solutions include global variables, or storing the received data in hidden input elements.

Within each callback function, just loop until the data from the other call is present:

```
function getJson1(){
    $.getJSON('url1',function(data){
        var d2 = '';
        $('#hidden1').val(data);
        while ( d2 == '' ){
            //you should use a time delay here
            d2 = $('#hidden2').val();
        }
        getJson2();
    });
}
function getJson2(){
    $.getJSON('url2',function(d2){
        var d1 = '';
        $('#hidden2').val(d2);
        while ( d1 == '' ){
            //you should use a time delay here
            d1 = $('#hidden1').val();
        }
        //Do stuff with json1 and json2 data
    });
}
getJson1();
```